# PHP - Unexpected array_merge_recursive() output

Tags: php, array-merge

I have this code

```
$a1 = array(
    'success'    => TRUE,
    'data'       => array(
        'foo' =>
        array(
            21 =>
            array(
                1 =>
                array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
            )
        )
    )
);

$a2 = array(
    'success'    => TRUE,
    'data'       => array(
        'foo' =>
        array(
            21 =>
            array(
                7 =>
                array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
            )
        )
    )
);

$results = array();
$results = array_merge_recursive($results, $a1['data']);
$results = array_merge_recursive($results, $a2['data']);
var_dump($results);
```

From what I understood of array_merge_recursive(), I am expecting the results would be

```
array
  'foo' => 
    array
      21 => 
        array
          1 => 
            array
              0 => int 1
              1 => int 2
              2 => int 3
              3 => int 4
              4 => int 5
           7 =>
              0 => int 6
              1 => int 7
              2 => int 8
              3 => int 9
              4 => int 10
```

Instead I get this

```
array
  'foo' => 
    array
      21 => 
        array
          1 => 
            array
              0 => int 1
              1 => int 2
              2 => int 3
              3 => int 4
              4 => int 5
      22 => 
        array
          7 => 
            array
              0 => int 6
              1 => int 7
              2 => int 8
              3 => int 9
              4 => int 10
```

Where did the `22` index come from? Why is it outputting differently? Did I use the function wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_merge_recursive` merges elements/arrays from the same depth as the first array, but if both arrays the key is a numerical index and they are the same it then appends to it. This is what is happening in your situation. since then your array is appended at 2nd level where index `21` is found by creating index `22`. To receive the desired output you have change your index `21` to a string key like `"x21"`

Notes from php manual

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the values for
>   these keys are merged together into an array, and this is done
>   recursively, so that if one of the values is an array itself, the
>   function will merge it with a corresponding entry in another array
>   too. If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later
>   value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue, I wanted to merge the arrays but surprisingly found the keys were changed automatically in the result. The reason was because my "keys" are string of decimal numbers, without any alphabetic characters.

But luckily I noticed that if the keys have alphabetic characters, they could be reserved. So just came up with the following idea, which would append a letter 'S' to each key recursively before the merge, and later remove it in the final result.

Please refer to the `enhanced_array_merge_recursive` function for details:

```
<?php

$aa = [
  '10' => 'book',
  '14' => ['cat'],
];

$ab = [
  '12' => 'cd',
  '18' => 'cup',
  '14' => ['dog'],
];

var_dump(enhanced_array_merge_recursive($aa, $ab));

function revise_keys($source)
{
    if (!is_array($source)) {
        return $source;
    }

    $target = [];

    foreach ($source as $key => $value) {
        $target['S' . $key] = revise_keys($value);
    }

    return $target;
}

function revert_keys($source)
{
    if (!is_array($source)) {
        return $source;
    }

    $target = [];

    foreach ($source as $key => $value) {
        $target[substr($key, 1 - strlen($key))] = revert_keys($value);
    }

    return $target;
}

function enhanced_array_merge_recursive(...$candidates)
{
    $merged = [];

    foreach ($candidates as $candidate) {
        if (!is_array($candidate)) {
            continue;
        }

        $merged = array_merge_recursive($merged, revise_keys($candidate));
    }

    return revert_keys($merged);
}
```

Output looks like following:

```
array(4) {
  [10] =>
  string(4) "book"
  [14] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    array(2) {
      [0] =>
      string(3) "cat"
      [1] =>
      string(3) "dog"
    }
  }
  [12] =>
  string(2) "cd"
  [18] =>
  string(3) "cup"
}
```